# How to exctract specific data and file name form multiple excel files pladec in one folder?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

I am looking for a solution to shorten the time of going through the excel files during tender preparation.
I was thinking of creatin a master excel file that would be placed above the folder which would contain all excel files i want to extract. I would like to extract the name of the file and place it in the specific column, and summarized data from one row in that file, to be placed in ther counterpart in the master folder. Main project folder can be located on any hard drives location. The master file and parts files would have the same layout inside.

The Structure would look like :

Project folder "some name">>
Master tender file,
Folder for parts calculation>>
Excel calculation for part 1,
Excel calculation for part n,

Is it possible to do something like that? i am learnig vba but the thing i did up until now is code for clearing the master file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad and non specific. Besides, it can lead to opinion-based answers. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Yes, it is possible! What did you try by your own?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.